# Matrix mutiplication using generics

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

```
public Matrix<T, A> multiply(Matrix<T, A> right) throws MatrixException {
    Matrix<T, A> temp = new Matrix<T, A>(arithmetics, rowSize, columnSize);



    if (rowSize != right.columnSize)
        throw new MatrixException(
                "Cannot multiply matrices of different sizes");

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < right.columnSize ; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < right.rowSize ; k++)
            temp.matrix[i][j] = arithmetics.add(temp.matrix[i][j],
         (arithmetics.multiply(matrix[i][k], right.matrix[k][j])));

    return temp;

}}
```

Alright So i am trying to mutiply 2 matrices but

```
Matrix1
0 0 1
1 1 1 

Matrix5
1 2
2 4
3 6
```

I GET AN answer of

```
Matrix1 multiply Matrix5
3   6   0   
6   12  0
```

but it should be

```
3 6
6 12
```

because it matrices mutiplication

Comment: It sure looks like you're creating the result matrix with the wrong dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

In your second line:

```
Matrix<T, A> temp = new Matrix<T, A>(arithmetics, rowSize, columnSize);
```

it must be:

```
Matrix<T, A> temp = new Matrix<T, A>(arithmetics, rowSize, right.columnSize);
```